# Failed dual boot working just changing BIOS boot settings. No GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows-10, bios

I have two hard drives:

1. I'm using one of them to storage (acting as an external HDD)
2. I'm using to installing OSs, which includes Windows and Ubuntu's `/` and `/home`.

I've deleted all the partitions of **2** and formatted **1** to exFAT (just for storage, as I said). Well, after this I installed Windows 10 (using UEFI, as Rufus just let me use this) on the "free space", letting Windows do the partitioning as the disk had no partitions at all. After having Windows installed, I shrank the `C:`'s partition in 50% and got some free space.

After that I started Ubuntu's live CD to install this Linux system using the USB mode in BIOS (not UEFI), because I had a broken installation using UEFI. I then created a new partition using the free space originated from `C:`'s shrinkage to be `/`'s. (Note: Ubuntu seemed not to detect W10, as no "Dual boot" option was offered).

Now, with the installation of both systems, I can boot through both of them (Not easily, though) changing boot order to "Windows Boot Loader" for loading Windows and my disk to loading Ubuntu.

Is there a way of getting GRUB to do this boot change for me? In case of any missing information here, please ask for it in the comments, as I don't know which information would be useful here.

I've googled it but I couldn't find the solution to this.

Comment: If you want Grub to manage dual boot you have to install both OS in the same boot mode, both UEFI or both legacy (BIOS).

Comment: Is there any way to manage this using other method?

Comment: If you installed Windows in UEFI mode, you can convert a BIOS install of Ubuntu just be reinstalling the UEFI version of grub or grub-efi-amd64. You can use Boot-Repair, but must  boot live installer in UEFI mode to make UEFI repairs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair